# weird can not find symbo '@IntDef' but AndroidStudio shows no error

Tags: java, android, annotations, chromium, androidx

[my Android Studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaViX.png)

Android Studio build failed with displaying message: can not find symbol '@IntDef', but the java code showing in IDE shows no error, as you can see in link, the class is successfully imported and I can find it in the "External Libraries" inside the project-view of Android Studio, also I find it in build-path while running with gralew xxx --debug --stacktrace.

I'm migrating google's chromium project into Android Studio project, the commit ID is 'b4a3bf71d7762468ad6ecf2e1461ff2135473063'. The code mixing support.v4.* with androidx.annotation and androidx.browser, I modified the gradle.properties with 'android.useAndroidX=true' and 'android.enableJetifier=false' so that Android Studio shows both the packages are successfully imported, but failed to build with the 'can not find symbol' error.

Also, I have written a simple demo to prove the mixing-usage is OK, but I doubt it. I also remove all possible none-java file in the source directory, including python-script, OWNERS, DEPS, some aidl files, but still get the same error. I don't known why there is a build error.

Maybe the build.gradle file can cause this error?

```
rootProject.ext.clsDefineChromiumFlavors(project)

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/deps/java'

    main.res.srcDirs += 'src/main/res_chromium'
    main.res.srcDirs += 'src/main/res_template'
    main.res.srcDirs += 'src/main/res_vr'

    abi_arm32 {
        java.srcDirs += 'flavor_src/abi_arm32/annotation_processor_output/java'
        java.srcDirs += 'flavor_src/abi_arm32/input_srcjars/java'
        java.srcDirs += 'flavor_src/abi_arm32/others/java'

        res.srcDirs += 'flavor_res/abi_arm32/chrome/res'
        res.srcDirs += 'flavor_res/abi_arm32/chrome/app/policy/res'
        res.srcDirs += 'flavor_res/abi_arm32/components/strings/res'
    }
    abi_arm64 {

    }
}
```

the closure definition is here:

```
// closure: define chromium flavors
ext.clsDefineChromiumFlavors = { curProject ->
    if (curProject == null) {
        return
    }
    curProject.android.flavorDimensions 'default'
    curProject.android.productFlavors {
        abi_arm32 {}
        abi_arm64 {}
        all { flavor ->
            curProject.android.sourceSets[flavor.name].setRoot("flavor_src/${flavor.name}")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SuppressLint is since Added in API level 16, so you need to upgrade to API level 16.

Another solution is to add `appcompat-v7` to your project build.gradle.

Also, make sure this is included:

```
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
```

Comment: My android build tool's version 3.6.1, target sdk verion 28, min is 19, androidx annotation used 1.1.0 already...

Comment: @QUANZhao have you found any solution to it? i'm facing the same issue.